# UserControl para controlar Horários de Logon

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, devexpress

Como eu poderia fazer em um *user control* do *Visual Studio* uma tela parecida com esta imagem abaixo, em um *ASCX(HTML,CSS,JS)*:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei com várias `<div>`, mas creio que ficaria um processamento muito longo, além que eu acho que é possível fazer com pouquíssimas linhas..

Eu uso também o *DevExpress* se servir de ajuda para algum iluminado!

Comment: Você se refere aos dias da semana e aos horarios na parte de cima?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se entendi o seu problema, você esta com dificuldade em gerar a parte html, css, js e não necessariamente um problema com `UserControl`. Não tenho muito conhecimento de ferramentas microsoft, mas já que o problema é mais com o html, css e js então vou tentar formular uma resposta.

Vou dizer algo que acho importante "discutir" aqui, todos pensam que em *webstandards* ou *tableless* é o desuso das tabelas em favor dos divs e outros. Mas na verdade o tableless se refere ao desuso errado (não semantico) das tabelas, exemplos de onde usar e não usar:

- Se a estrutura que pretende criar é para dados tabulares, então sim, use tabelas
- Vai criar uma planilha online, então sim, use tabelas
- Se você vai fazer um menu em lista então não use tabela
- Se vai fazer três colunas para conteúdos variados então não use tabelas

Não vou entrar muito em detalhes, mas olhando o seu desenho me parece uma estrutura totalmente tabular, então deve usar `<table>`, `<tr>`, `<th>`, `<td>`, etc.

Um exemplo seria assim:

```css
.minhatabela th, .minhatabela td {
    border: 1px #ccc solid;
}
```

```html
<table class="minhatabela">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Todos</th>
            <th>00:00</th>
            <th>01:00</th>
            <th>02:00</th>
            <th>03:00</th>
            <th>04:00</th>
            <th>05:00</th>
            <th>06:00</th>
            <th>07:00</th>
            <th>08:00</th>
            <th>09:00</th>
            <th>10:00</th>
            <th>11:00</th>
            <th>12:00</th>
            <th>13:00</th>
            <th>14:00</th>
            <th>15:00</th>
            <th>16:00</th>
            <th>17:00</th>
            <th>18:00</th>
            <th>19:00</th>
            <th>20:00</th>
            <th>21:00</th>
            <th>22:00</th>
            <th>23:00</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Domingo</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Segunda</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Terça</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Quarta</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Quinta</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sexta</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sabado</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

No entanto acredito que você também queira o efeito de selecionar as celulas da tabela, um bom exemplo é o código usado nesta [pergunta no soen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20942564/1518921), ficaria assim:

```js
$(function () {
    var table = $('.minhatabela');
    var cells = $('.minhatabela td:not(:first-child)');
    cells.mousedown(function () {
        cells.removeClass('selected');
        var start = {
            x: this.cellIndex,
            y: this.parentNode.rowIndex
        }
        cells.mouseover(function () {
            var x1 = Math.min(start.x, this.cellIndex);
            var y1 = Math.min(start.y, this.parentNode.rowIndex);
            var x2 = Math.max(start.x, this.cellIndex);
            var y2 = Math.max(start.y, this.parentNode.rowIndex);

            cells.each(function () {
                var x = this.cellIndex;
                var y = this.parentNode.rowIndex;
                if (x >= x1 && x <= x2 && y >= y1 && y <= y2) {
                    $(this).addClass('selected');
                } else {
                    $(this).removeClass('selected');
                }
            });
        });

        $(document).mouseup(function () {
            cells.unbind('mouseover');
            $(document).unbind('mouseup');
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.minhatabela th, .minhatabela td {
    border: 1px #ccc solid;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    height:30px;
    -moz-user-select:none;
    -webkit-user-select:none;
    user-select:none;
}
.minhatabela .selected {
    background-color: #fc0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="minhatabela">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Todos</th>
            <th>00:00</th>
            <th>01:00</th>
            <th>02:00</th>
            <th>03:00</th>
            <th>04:00</th>
            <th>05:00</th>
            <th>06:00</th>
            <th>07:00</th>
            <th>08:00</th>
            <th>09:00</th>
            <th>10:00</th>
            <th>11:00</th>
            <th>12:00</th>
            <th>13:00</th>
            <th>14:00</th>
            <th>15:00</th>
            <th>16:00</th>
            <th>17:00</th>
            <th>18:00</th>
            <th>19:00</th>
            <th>20:00</th>
            <th>21:00</th>
            <th>22:00</th>
            <th>23:00</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Domingo</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Segunda</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Terça</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Quarta</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Quinta</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sexta</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sabado</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Renan, nesse caso você precisa criar uma tabela.

Na primeira linha você vai colocar os horários(12.2.4.6.8, etc) em um [thead](http://www.infowester.com/tagsdesconhecidas2.php).

Na segunda linha você vai colocar, na primeira coluna, os dias da semana(All, Sunday, Monday, etc) e as demais colunas servirão para deixar as lacunas para o usuário clicar e deixar marcado.

Quando o usuário clicar no campo você vai precisar [capturar](http://loopinfinito.com.br/2013/05/14/entendendo-captura-e-propagacao-de-eventos/) esse evento no JavaScript e gravar em algum local, seja com um serviço via [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/AJAX), [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie), etc.

Da uma olhada no código [desses calendários](http://www.cssflow.com/snippets/tag/calendar) para você ter uma base mais ou menos de como fazer. Aqui também tem um exemplo até com [Datepicker](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3604/calendario-em-jquery-criando-calendarios-com-datepicker.aspx) se lhe for interessante.

Espero ter ajudado. :D

Comment: Olá, foi de grande ajuda a sua resposta! Mas eu ainda estou emperrado na parte em que capturo o evento.. Como eu poderia realizar isto por javascript para cada campo clicado? Pois após clicar no botão Salvar, ele irá incluir ao sql para mim cada valor, dentro do dia da semana..

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, certa vez precisei desenvolver algo parecido, porém bem menos complexo, usei uma tabela, e no miolo coloquei um DataList, o legal do datalist é que em cada ItemTemplate você tem liberdade para colocar elementos HTML ou ASP. Dessa forma pode ficar mais fácil para controlar os eventos, até mesmo sem usar javascript. Dá uma olhada aqui na [documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0603s5x0(v=vs.85).aspx) e veja se lhe ajuda um pouco.